# How to assign scalar query to report viewer in C#

Tags: c#, sql

My problem is that i need 2 same rows to be sum for this i use scalar query SUM in dataset, if you have any other suggestion kindly reply.

In this scenario when i assign:

```
this.saleTableAdapter.ScalarQuery(this.SaleDateset.sale);
```

it shows:

```
No overload method "Scalar Query" takes 1 argument.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Moxet khana... tam rale stackoverflow ta haha

Answer (score 0):

'ScalarQuery' is your own function. There may be one more parameter is required for it.

**No overload method "Scalar Query" takes 1 argument.** this is a compile time errors for asking the more than 1 Parameter for "ScalarQuery" function.